# Can magic items be broken by physical attacks in AL?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

My AL character has a *staff of charming* that one DM thinks is too overpowered, and he wants to ban it. The *staff of charming* was stolen by an enemy in AL DDEX 1-10, and was bent with a Strength check of 21.

My DM says that according to the AL FAQ v6.1, there is no rule that says permanent magic items can't be broken. I know that magic items usually lose their magic when they are broken.

Is the staff irreparably broken?

Comment: His strength check actually does not really matter, if your DM declares the result "Your staff is now bent." Did your DM say that your staff is broken as the result? Usually an ALDM does not permanently remove a magic item after a session (since you worked hard - using 'real life time and effort' to get TP/gold to buy that). What do they say after the session end?

Comment: @V2Blast I believe the point of this question is in the part that asks "Is my staff **irreparably broken**", emphasis mine. OP wants his staff, and seems not to care if it couldn't be broken in the first place, or was broken and relatively easily repaired.

Comment: Well,he think it's too op,so he wants to ban it.Even if l tell him the Al faq 8.2 has answer,the staff can't be broken by physical attack.

He says the enemy change his action to rob the staff and escape away.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your question says bent, and then it says broken.  Which happened?

Comment: Following up Korvin's comment, you also state that the DM (may have?) retconned it to stolen and that they just didn't want you to have it anymore. I think you need to decide if you're asking: 1)Can you *mend* a magic item to fix it?, 2)Can a magic item be broken? or 3) Can an AL DM take away magic items (either by breaking or by stealing them?

Comment: Related on [Does breaking a magic item render it useless?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119175/does-breaking-a-magic-item-render-it-useless) and [How can a damaged magic item be repaired?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143747/how-can-a-damaged-magic-item-be-repaired)

Comment: How did the enemy take your staff?

Comment: Could you clarify if you're asking if the GM was allowed to break the item or if you just want to know if/how to repair it?

Comment: Also, I don't recommend playing with this GM again. They're clearly not wanting to follow AL guidance nor the spirit of play (you can't simply ban a magic item, staff or otherwise because you don't like it). I understand some people have trouble finding GM's (especially organized play, sometimes) but I would recommend you put in the effort to do so.

Answer (score 9):

## Most permanent magic items cannot be destroyed

The latest version of the AL FAQ (v9.0, p. 9) states:

> ### Destroying Magic Items
>
> Unless the conditions of an item's destruction is specifically stated (talon card from *deck of many things*, *ioun stone*, *+2 nets, etc.*) permanent magic items can't be destroyed.

The *staff of charming* only mentions the following means of becoming nonmagical:

> If you expend the last charge, roll a d20. On a 1, the staff becomes a nonmagical quarterstaff.

Your DM is using a (very) outdated version of the FAQ, which did not contain guidance about magic item destruction. **The only way the *staff of charming* could be destroyed is by you choosing to spend the last charge, rolling a 1, and then someone could damage or destroy it.**

Answer (score 5):

#### Rules guidance says the DM cannot arbitrarily destroy your magic items in Adventurer's League.

[image: Magic items cannot be destroyed at the whim of the DM. Just like its not up to the DM if a character's body is destroyed, both cases must be called out by the creature or adventure to be possible. This prevents a vindictive DM from permanently destroying an item or character and puts the fate of the character and their hard won magic items in the hands of the owning player.]

> Magic items cannot be destroyed at the whim of the DM. Just like its not up to the DM if a character's body is destroyed, both cases must be called out by the creature or adventure to be possible. This prevents a vindictive DM from permanently destroying an item or character and puts the fate of the character and their hard won magic items in the hands of the owning player.

According to the [D&D AL FAQ v6.1](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/DDAL_FAQv6-1.pdf), any official rules guidance posted to Facebook is official:

> Any rules guidance given by an Admin using the #AL_Admin or #AL_Official hashtag is considered official rules guidance. In time, it may be added to this FAQ and made available without the drudgery of having to resort to Facebook’s “search” function.

#### Mending a magic item?

If a magic item is broken, *mending* specifically cannot repair it, according to the spell description (*Player's Handbook* p.259):

> This spell can physically repair a magic item or construct, but the spell can't restore magic to such an object.

This implies that a broken magic item loses its magic, although strictly speaking there's no rule that this is the case. It's entirely up to the DM whether a broken magic item can be repaired.

Comment: The latest version of the [AL FAQ, v8.2](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/FAQv82.pdf#page=5) also contains the same statement on Facebook guidance: "***Social Media (Facebook/Google+, Etc.).*** Rules guidance given by an Admin using the #AL_Admin or #AL_Official hashtag is considered official rules guidance. In time, it may be added to this FAQ." Also, as mentioned in Chris' answer, the issue is also explicitly addressed in the FAQ itself.