# Is it possible to restore HP to an object that has HP?

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-points, objects

I asked a question a month ago, specifically about the Apparatus of Kwalich. I also asked whether or not this Apparatus could regain HP. This has been largely unaswered. So, *can an object with HP regain HP*?

Comment: Since you stated this was because those questions weren't answered in your original, I've marked this as a duplicate. If it isn't, and you aren't interested in the Kwalish example, that's fine, but please clarify. If it is, please bounty your first question with the request that it's missing information.

Comment: @NautArch I don't think this is actually a duplicate.  While in the previous question "does it regain hit points?" was asked, it was neither the title question nor properly part of the requested information.  It was really a tacked-on side question, which is appropriate to break out into a separate ask. I'd just recommend asking it plainly here instead of referencing another question.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym It is in the body of the duplicate question. OP wanted that info on that question, didn't get it, and asked again here. It is a duplicate and should be bountied - unless they aren't asking about the Kwalish item (which may or may not have different rules), in which case asking generally about objects would be a different question. But if it's about Kwalish, which this question says specifically it is, then it's a dupe.

Comment: I think https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143747/how-can-a-damaged-magic-item-be-repaired would be a better duplicate reference

Comment: @DarthPseudonym, I agree, Much better duplicate.